# How to detect browser close or tab close event in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, session, dom-events

I am trying to detect browser or tab close event for Chrome, so that I can invalidate the session for my Java web application. I have tried `onbeforeload()` and `unload()`, but these functions are called when the content of page is unloaded within my web application. Also I am unable to override these functions in Javascript for Chrome browser.

Is there any way I can find browser close or tab close event for Chrome and make an ajax call and invalidate the session?